# Waiting room in Play Games Multiplayer does not show connected players

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-play-games

I use the Real Time Multiplayer Support of the Google Play Games Services in one of my game apps. The Auto Match Config is specified like this:

```
Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(7, 7, 0);
```

Therefore it will create a game with 6 players. I have now the following problem:

Let's say there are already 4 people connected to the waiting room, then they will not see each other. So they are not aware that other people are already connected. The names of the player will only be revealed if all 7 participants are connected. This behavior does not motivate people to stay in the waiting room until all players are connected, because to them it appears like if they are alone waiting.

The image below shows the waiting room. Two people were already connected, but the player can only see them-self. The strings 'auto-pick' will be replaced with player names when the room is full which is too late.

[image: Waiting room]

How can I show the real state of the waiting room to players? I wan't to motivate them to stay in the waiting room.

Gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:mediarouter-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:customtabs:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.billingclient:billing:1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.2'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-appstate:6.5.87'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:16.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:16.0.0'
```

That's how the game is created:

```
   void startQuickGame() {
    final int MAX_OPPONENTS = 6;
    int min_opponents = 6;
    Bundle autoMatchCriteria = RoomConfig.createAutoMatchCriteria(min_opponents,
            MAX_OPPONENTS, 0);
    RoomConfig.Builder rtmConfigBuilder = RoomConfig.builder(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setMessageReceivedListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setRoomStatusUpdateListener(this);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setAutoMatchCriteria(autoMatchCriteria);
    rtmConfigBuilder.setVariant(variant);
    switchToScreen(R.id.mpGamescreen_wait);
    keepScreenOn();

    Games.RealTimeMultiplayer.create(mGoogleApiClient, rtmConfigBuilder.build());
    }
```

The above method `startQuickGame();` was called inside `onConnected(Bundle connectionHint)` method. The onActivityResult looks like:

```
    @Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);

    switch (requestCode) {
        case RC_SELECT_PLAYERS:
            // we got the result from the "select players" UI -- ready to create the room
            handleSelectPlayersResult(responseCode, intent);
            break;
        case RC_WAITING_ROOM:
            // we got the result from the "waiting room" UI.
            if (responseCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
                // ready to start playing
                Log.d(TAG, "debug Starting game (waiting room returned OK).");
                //startGameHandler(true);
            } else if (responseCode == GamesActivityResultCodes.RESULT_LEFT_ROOM) {
                // player indicated that they want to leave the room
                leaveRoom();
            } else if (responseCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                // Dialog was cancelled (user pressed back key, for instance). In our game,
                // this means leaving the room too. In more elaborate games, this could mean
                // something else (like minimizing the waiting room UI).
                leaveRoom();
            }
            break;
        case RC_SIGN_IN:
            Log.d(TAG, "debug onActivityResult with requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN, responseCode="
                + responseCode + ", intent=" + intent);
            mSignInClicked = false;
            mResolvingConnectionFailure = false;
            if (responseCode == RESULT_OK) {
              mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            } else {
              BaseGameUtils.showActivityResultError(this,requestCode,responseCode, R.string.signin_other_error);
            }
            break;
    }
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, responseCode, intent);
}
```

The API Client was created like this in oncreate. Please note some methods are deprecated (should switch to GoogleSignIn in future).

```
        // Create the Google Api Client with access to Plus and Games
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        //.addApi(Plus.API).addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
        .addApi(Games.API).addScope(Games.SCOPE_GAMES)
        .build();
```

Any hint or workaround is welcome.

Answer (score 1):

How about your RoomStatusUpdate listener?
[RoomStatusUpdateCallback](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/realtime/RoomStatusUpdateCallback)
Do you implement the onPeerJoined(Room room, List participantIds) method ?

Comment: Yes I have this method. It will call updateRoom() and the only code line inside updateRoom is: mParticipants = room.getParticipants();. Is there any chance that I can modify the waiting room inside this method, so that it will update the screen?